# How can I create function on ajax event (onreadystatechange)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am very much new in ajax . 
Trying  to understand through the [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqRiDlm-SnY)

trying code :

```
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC" ..//w3c//DTDXHTML 1.0 strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>ajax</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function getScores() {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange() = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = "<strong>Sonal Goyal</strong>"
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.learntoprogram.tv/baseball.php", true);

        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="score"></div>
    <input type="button" value="get scores!" onclick="getScores()" />
</body>
</html>
```

where I am lacking?

Comment: First replace 'scores' with 'score' or the other way around

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine to me except that you have a spelling mistake in you input-divContainer id.

To find out what is the error output xmlhttp data in your else 
clause

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange() = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = xmlhttp.status;
            }
        }
```

Comment: here I am getting output: sonal goyal but instead i want some other text . Which was in my file .

Comment: That means you had an error during the Ajax request. Output xmlhttp.readystate and xmlhttp.status in your else clause. That will give us a clue what went wrong.

Comment: By the way I would suggest you to allways use var to define variables, even if it's working without. And in this special case I would put the xmlhttp definition inside your function. This is good for not polluting the global scope.

Comment: k can you pls tell me Ajax with Json or Ajax with dojo is both things are same

Comment: Json is a subset of the object literal notation and can for example be used to transform php object in the right form to be presented in JS. For more detailed info just Google it. Dojo is little framework that is giving you some shorthand function (not only) for Ajax request. Also to be mentioned then is jQuery which is (I think) a bigger framework which I find very useful for a lot of things as well as Ajax.